# Child Theme problems

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, child-theme, child-pages

I have a Premium WordPress theme that I created a child theme on. I can change the regular WordPress php pages and the css on the parent theme inside the child theme with no problems. Inside the premium theme has its own css and its own custom php pages in separate folders.

I can get the css working by `wp_enqueue_style` inside the child themes `functions.php`, and I have copied the folders folders from the premium theme into the child theme, but I can not get the php pages inside the folders of the premium theme to work or have the changes show up when I make changes to them.

I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track
First off.
 Start with a `css` file.

```
/*
Theme Name: 
Theme URI: 
Description: 
Author: 
Author URI:
Version:
Template: 
*/
@import url("../{theme_name}/style.css");
```

If you overwrite styles:
Only write the classes and ids you want to overwrite and end them with an `!important`
for example:

```
.container{
    margin:0 0 0 50px !important;
}
```

Only copy the files you want to overwrite, not the entire theme.
Create a functions.php in your child-theme folder and enqueue the child theme css file

```
Function wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'childstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'childstyle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 11);
```

This should get you going....

Comment: Do not use `@import`. It is greatly discouraged. There are a few posts on site as to why not to use `@import`

Comment: Interesting. please tell/show me why...

Comment: @Interactive - [see this](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) for an explanation.